# Disable dedicated GPU device in GRUB

Tags: boot, grub, gpu, kernel, pci

I need some help. :(
My laptop has Ryzen 5 2500u with Vega 8 graphics card and a dedicated gpu RX560x.
The OS is Linux Mint Tricia Cinnamon based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
My dedicated gpu is momentarily dead and i can use just the integrated one (i made some test on Windows 10 and the integrated one has no problem, and yes I have a Dual Boot).
The problem is in Linux, cause the kernel module name of the integrated and dedicated gpu is both "amdgpu".
Now for pass the boot in Linux without errors, I must put in grub or "nomodeset" or "modprobe.blacklist=amdgpu".
The point is that I want to use only my integreted gpu and not disable both with these instructions.
Can I put in /ect/default/grub an instruction that disable the SPECIFIC PCI ID device? And not blacklist the kernel module name cause both gpu has the same "name". Just the PCI ID is different.
With lspci the integrated is 04:00.0 and the dedicated is 01:00.0.
I need just an instruction that disable the pci 01:00.0 before the system boots.
Thanks in advice guys!

---

@Eugen Rieck, this is the output of "lspci -tv"

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d0
           +-00.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15d1
           +-01.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
           +-01.1-[01]----00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/560]
           +-01.6-[02]--+-00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader
           |            \-00.1  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           +-01.7-[03]----00.0  Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           +-08.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
           +-08.1-[04]--+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
           |            +-00.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 15de
           |            +-00.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15df
           |            +-00.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e0
           |            +-00.4  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e1
           |            \-00.6  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e3
           +-08.2-[05]----00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
           +-14.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller
           +-14.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge
           +-18.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e8
           +-18.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e9
           +-18.2  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ea
           +-18.3  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15eb
           +-18.4  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ec
           +-18.5  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ed
           +-18.6  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ee
           \-18.7  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15ef
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy trick: Reserve you discrete GPU for KVM passthrough without ever actually passing it to a VM:

- find your PCI vendor and device ID (e.g. 1002:67ef)
- add `vfio-pci.ids=1002:67ef` to your kernel command line via GRUB (ofcourse using the correct IDs)

This way, on boot Linux will not use the device as a GPU but assigne it the vfio-driver, so neuters it if no passthrough is assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After put that instruction in grub, save, exit, update-grub, reboot. The Notebook is stuck on ACER logo. I have to force shutdown with power off button. It doesnt go in booting mode. In Windows 10 is all great. I go in Devices --> disable device. DONE. And play with iGPU with no problem. Maybe i have to blacklist some pci-e bridge of the dGPU that is still ON after that instruction. And obviusly that pci-e bridge is corrupt.

Comment: How did you "put that instruction in grub"? It seems you messed up your grub.cfg

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ro quiet splash vfio-pci.ids=1002:67ef"

Comment: Post output of `lspci -tv`

Comment: If you are stuck at the Acer logo, then maybe the kernel doesn't start - so 'vfio-pci.ids=1002:67ef' might never be read. Start by removing "quiet splash" from the boot options and make sure you have set the IGPU as primary in the BIOS

Comment: Hello Eugen! My BIOS is awful, I have no options for this kind of stuff. Now i try to remove "quiet splash" but I know it will not work.. Did you saw my lspci -tv output?

Comment: If you can't set the IGPU as primary, you can't see the boot process - there's no workaround for that. You can try `video=vesafb:off,efifb:off` and maybe the KVM passthrough tricks like `amd_iommu=on rd.driver.pre=vfio-pci` to detach the dGPU as early as possible.

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=vesafb:off,efifb:off". Boot process stucked at "sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk".

Comment: sdb seems strange - what is sda? Are you sure that 1002:67ef is the correct PCI id?

Comment: If sdb is the card reader, you might need to blacklist it - it's on the same PCIe bus as the dGPU

Comment: I Blacklisted in grub both like this                    "vfio-pci.ids=1002:67ef,10ec:5287", but still boot process stuck on [sdb] Attached SCSI disk

Comment: I ment blackiisting ((via `blacklist`) not vfio

Comment: Disable GPU in grub with "vfio" and Card Reader with? Sorry, noobie here.

Comment: find out which driver is controlling the reader, then blacklist it via /etc/modprobe/*.conf. First make sure, there is no card in the reader.

Comment: I moved the topic here https://superuser.com/questions/1535435/cannot-boot-into-linux?noredirect=1#comment2329523_1535435 . Nothing helped here :(